# how to access and configure wifi repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, mac-address, nmap, repeater

My 5G signal does not penetrate through the whole house, so I figured I buy a WiFi repeater. This is installed and seems to work. However once I set up the WiFi inside the repeater it restarts and exposes 2 new WiFi SSIDs (a 2.4G and a 5G). I can connect to those and get internet. So far so good. But now I want to configure the device (remove default login, change channel, etc) and somehow I can't...

There is a MAC address printed on the device, but doing a nmap scan of my subnet does not give me any matches on that MAC (scanning for port 80, because in the initial setup there was a webpage exposing the configuration page)...

```
sudo nmap -p 80 192.168.0.0/16
```

scanning from both WiFis the one exposed via the repeater and the one from the router.

Why am I not finding the repeater? Thanks in advance for any pointers...

EDIT:

[repeater model](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000074491748.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dtgIU37)

the [router model](https://www.wingo.ch/de/hilfe/internet-tv-fix/internet-box) is provided by the internet service provider.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and add the make and model of the router?

Comment: sure! sorry totally forgot about that

Comment: Did you follow the “documentation” on the Aliexpress site in your link and connect to one of the exposed SSIDs and visit 192.168.188.1? If not, why not?

Comment: yes, of course. that's how i set the device up in the first place, now it broadcasts a 5G and 2.4G signal as it should. but that same setup page is no longer exposed on that address now... and that is the reason for my confusion and question here